# Am I able to make an addin that includes a set of macros that it will use?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, macros, add-in

Before I talk about what I am trying to get done, here are all my details on what I have done:
I have made a Macro Project named "XSMacros"

Here is what I'd like to do:
I want to make a VS Add-In have my Macros embedded into it so that when on start up of Visual Studio, the add-in creates context menus items in the Code Window's Context Menu that use my macros.
Now, my question is, how can this be done? And specifically:

- Creating new menus inside the Code Window's context menu.
- Creating new menu command utens in the menus that I add to the Code Window's context menu.
- Call Macros from XSMacros when a specific command item is clicked.

  **(BUT, WITHOUT IMPORTING MY SETTING AND MY MACROS IN THE PERSON'S PROJECT.)**

  ***Also, I am using VS2010 and C# to program the Add-in!***

Answer (score 0):

You can add context items to Code Window like this:

```
CommandBars cmdBrs  = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars);

Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar codeWindowCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Code Window"];

CommandBarPopup myNewPopUpControl = codeWindowCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup) as CommandBarPopup;

myNewPopUpControl.Caption = "MyMenu";
myNewPopUpControl.Visible = true;
```

You can add further items as it is the Add-In template example for Tools menu.

Based on VS 2012 doesn't support Macros further you can migrate your macros into a VB assembly. This way you can improve compatibility supporting 2012 also, and your macros won't be exposed.

[MZ-Tools HOWTO: Migrate macro methods to a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013016.aspx)